# Building a calculator in Python

Tags: python, calculator

So I'm new to Python and the first thing I started working on was a calculator. The bulk of my code goes towards addressing incorrect inputs, but I was trying to figure out if there was a way to add/subtract/multiply/divide more than just two numbers. Like allow the user to choose how many numbers they wanted to operate and then put them all into the calculation. Really I'm just looking for any possible improvements, even more advanced things like getting it to differentiate or integrate functions and stuff. Any thoughts?

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
def mult(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2



def main():
    operation = raw_input('\n' "What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /): ")


    if (operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
    print("Please enter a valid operation")
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                var1 = float(raw_input("Enter num1: ")) 
                var2 = float(raw_input("Enter num2: "))
            except ValueError:
                print('\n' "Please enter numbers only")
                continue
            else:
                break   
        print('\n' "The answer is:")    
        if(operation == '+'):
            print(add(var1, var2))
        if(operation == '-'):
            print(sub(var1, var2))
        if(operation == '*'):
            print(mult(var1, var2)) 
        if(operation == '/'):
            try:
                print(div(var1, var2))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("Infinity!")                      
while True:
    main()
```

Output:

What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /): **+**

Enter num1: **6**

Enter num2: **4**

The answer is:

10.0

What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /): **r**

Please enter a valid operation

What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /):*

Enter num1: **1**

Enter num2: **e**

Please enter numbers only

Enter num1: **t**

Please enter numbers only

Enter num1: **2.345**

Enter num2: **4.67**

The answer is:

10.95115

What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /): **/**

Enter num1: **4**

Enter num2: **0**

The answer is:

Infinity!

What do you want to do? (+, -, *, /):

Comment: this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please read [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Look at [the example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/detail/pycalc.py) at the Pyparsing tutorial

Comment: You should ask this question in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things you could look at:

For multiple numbers, you might take a look at varargs, which let you put as many arguments as you want into a function. For example:

```
def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for number in args:
        sum += number
    return sum

print(add(1, 2, 4, 3)) # prints 10
```

The * means to take everything that was passed in after args, and put them in a list. That makes args a list, rather than a number, and you can just iterate through it.
You could use the split function to break up a list of numbers the user entered ("1 2 4 3".split()), then send them all into that function.

You could also look at having the user input a typical mathematical expression ("12 + 5 * 4 - 8"), then convert it to postfix notation and parse it, the way actual calculators handle this type of thing. This is quite a bit more complicated, but you'd learn a lot about Python! These links give more info on that process:
[Convert to postfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail) 
[Evaluate postfix expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm)